# Create a horizontal UICollectionView with Cell's height larger than view's height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've create a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`. I need to set the view's frame in fixed height.

However, some cells' height may be larger than the view's height. And when this cells shown, the console complains:

`the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
 the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
 Please check the values return by the delegate.`

My layout setting is as follow:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.f;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.f;
```

Section inset is set as `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

`UICollectionView` is set as fixed frame like `CGRectMake(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH, 100)`.

Cell's item size is changed dynamically based on the content. So sometimes it can be larger than the collection view's height(100).

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show your UICollectionViewFlowLayout ?

Comment: @anhtu I've added the layout setting. Please check it.

Comment: How about itemSize, sectionInset of UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and frame of UICollectionView?

Comment: @anhtu I've added more description.

Comment: That causes the console complains for sure. So you want the console don't complain?

Comment: @anhtu Yes. I would like that if cell's height is larger that view's height, It just been cropped instead of complain. I think I can achieve this through using `UIScrollView`, but `UIScrollView` needs more work to do some recycle jobs.

Comment: How about using UITableView?

Comment: @anhtu I think it is hard to use `UITableView` in horizontal scroll? Actually besides the complain in console, I also don't know how to make the cell stick to top of view when the cell's height is smaller than view's height.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about horizontal. For cell stick to top of view, you can use CollectionCell is an `UIView`, then using auto-layout for its children (instead of add directly children to Cell). "It just been cropped instead of complain" I don't understand this clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the poor English... I just want the extra part of cell be cropped(like `clipToBounds`) without the complain words showing up in the console.

Comment: So, it means, extra part of cell is cropped is ok?. So you can add a fixed UIView (height <= 100) to collectionCell. Than add actually view (what you want to display) (changed dynamically based on the content) to this fixed UIView. And use auto-layout (in fixed UIView) for stick to top of view

Comment: @anhtu I've tried but it failed. The console still gave me warnings.

Comment: `be less than`. Did you try with UIView height = ?

Comment: @anhtu Yes. I set the fixed UIView's height = 90. I think I've found the problem. It is because inside the `UICollectionViewCell` I'm using the other `UICollectionView`. The complain should come from the inner one now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?. I will write an answer for others, later.

Comment: @anhtu Actually after I located the problem, I found the lib `GMCPagingScrollView` and I decided to use it instead of the complex `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a fixed UIView (height < 100) to collectionCell. Then add actual view (what you want to display) (changed dynamically based on the content) to this fixed UIView.

P/s: OP found the lib `GMCPagingScrollView` for this kind of control also.

Comment: What If I want a horizontal UIcollectionview with its cells getting dynamic height? Is it even possible?